# SQL query with joined subqueries optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

The statement below is used to gather the numbers for how well products sell at our various grocery stores. Essentially, it is the same statement executed 4 times, with the difference being which store is checked, and then joined. Individually, each statement takes no longer than 5 seconds, but when joined, can take up to 2 minutes. I've tried moving and switching `ON` clauses, as well as `WHERE` clauses, and have had no luck. I know the reasoning is that each query must be processed before it can be joined, and narrowed down, but even still I would think it would only add up to ~20 seconds, not 120!

The statement is generated by another script, and changes depending on user input. This example returns 230 rows at 1 minute and 30 seconds.

```sql
SELECT store1.upc,store1.description,store1.size,store1.uom,store1.price,
        store_qty, store_weight, store_sales,
        O_qty, O_weight, O_sales,
        W_qty, W_weight, W_sales,
        S_qty, S_weight, S_sales
FROM
(
    SELECT itemdetail.upc, itemdetail.description, itemdetail.size, itemdetail.uom, itemdetail.price,
            sum(store.quantity) AS store_qty,
            sum(store.weight) AS store_weight,
            sum(store.sales) AS store_sales
    FROM movementweekly AS store
        LEFT JOIN itemdetail ON itemdetail.upc = store.upc 
    WHERE store.date BETWEEN '2017-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-09 00:00:00'
        AND ((itemdetail.upc >= 5100000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 5100099999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 51000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 51000999999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 510000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 510009999999))
    GROUP BY itemdetail.upc,itemdetail.description,itemdetail.size,itemdetail.uom,itemdetail.price
) AS store1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT O.upc, sum(O.quantity) AS O_qty, sum(O.weight) AS O_weight, sum(O.sales) AS O_sales 
        FROM movementweekly AS O
        LEFT JOIN itemdetail ON itemdetail.upc = O.upc 
        WHERE O.store = 1
            AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-09 00:00:00' 
            AND ((itemdetail.upc >= 5100000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 5100099999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 51000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 51000999999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 510000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 510009999999))
        GROUP BY O.upc
    ) AS O1 ON store1.upc = O1.upc  
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT W.upc, sum(W.quantity) AS W_qty, sum(W.weight) AS W_weight, sum(W.sales) AS W_sales 
        FROM movementdaily AS W
        LEFT JOIN itemdetail ON itemdetail.upc = W.upc 
        WHERE W.store = 2
            AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-09 00:00:00' 
            AND ((itemdetail.upc >= 5100000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 5100099999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 51000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 51000999999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 510000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 510009999999))
        GROUP BY W.upc
    ) AS W1 ON store1.upc = W1.upc
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT S.upc, sum(S.quantity) AS S_qty, sum(S.weight) AS S_weight, sum(S.sales) AS S_sales 
        FROM movementdaily AS S
            LEFT JOIN itemdetail ON itemdetail.upc = S.upc 
        WHERE S.store = 3
            AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-09 00:00:00' 
            AND ((itemdetail.upc >= 5100000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 5100099999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 51000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 51000999999) OR (itemdetail.upc >= 510000000000 AND itemdetail.upc <= 510009999999))
        GROUP BY S.upc
    ) AS S1 ON store1.upc = S1.upc
ORDER BY store_sales DESC
```

And here is the first five rows, as an example.
Ignore the weight columns being all zeros. It's used for other statements generated from the same template.

```
|UPC     |  |Description                 |  |size | |uom  | |Price| |Store_qty| |Store_weight|  |Store_sales|   |O_qty| |O_weight|  |O_Sales|   |W_qty| |W_weight|  |W_Sales|   |S_qty| |S_weight|  |S_Sales|
5100013279  Swanson Chicken Broth Red Sod   32      oz      2.99    614         0               1676.47         207     0           580.32      218     0           622.12      189     0           474.03
5100012114  Swanson Broth Chicken           32      oz      2.99    597         0               1616.73         148     0           414.8       201     0           565.35      248     0           636.58
5100018806  Swanson Chunk White Chicken     12.5    oz      3.49    382         0               1524.18         91      0           363.09      147     0           586.53      144     0           574.56
5100000011  Campbells Tomato Soup           10.75   oz      0.99    1499        0               1432.71         624     0           590.59      490     0           475.41      387     0           368.69
5100000803  V8 Vegetable Juice              46      oz      3.39    454         0               1400.11         200     0           602.24      192     0           594.80      62      0           203.06
```

Comment: If I understand what your query is doing, you could put this all into a single query (without joins) using case aggregation. e.g. Using your first subquery, you alter it to add `o_qty = SUM(CASE WHEN store = 1 THEN...)` etc. Or something like that (possibly using an SUM() OVER() clause if necessary). It would help to see some sample data / output to better visualise what your query does.

Comment: @zlk example data has been added

Comment: Oh, right, I just realised you're selecting from different tables (movementdaily vs movementweekly). But from the look of it, the data is replicated in both tables? The sum() in the week table seems to align with the sum() in the daily tables. Is there a need to join the daily table if it's all in the weekly table?

Comment: Assuming all the data is in the weekly table, you could just modify your `store1` subquery to add additional fields. So, for example, `O_qty = SUM(CASE WHEN store.store = 1 THEN store.quantity END), O_weight = SUM(CASE WHEN store.store = 1 THEN store.weight END)... W_qty = SUM(CASE WHEN store.store = 2 THEN store.quantity END)... S_qty = SUM(CASE WHEN store.store = 3 THEN store.quantity END)...` etc (and you'd remove all the joins because they're unnecessary) and if it still runs slowly then it might be an issue with whatever indexes you currently have on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
-- you can select all the necessary items into temporary table
SELECT upc, description, size, uom, price
INTO #temp_itemdetail
FROM itemdetail
WHERE ((upc >= 5100000000 AND upc <= 5100099999) OR (upc >= 51000000000 AND upc <= 51000999999) OR (upc >= 510000000000 AND upc <= 510009999999))

-- add primary key into temp table
ALTER TABLE #temp_itemdetail ADD PRIMARY KEY(upc)

-- and you can use two subqueries instead four
SELECT
  q1.upc,q1.description,q1.size,q1.uom,q1.price,
  q1.store_qty, q1.store_weight, q1.store_sales,
  q1.O_qty, q1.O_weight, q1.O_sales,
  q2.W_qty, q2.W_weight, q2.W_sales,
  q2.S_qty, q2.S_weight, q2.S_sales
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      i.upc, i.description, i.size, i.uom, i.price,

      sum(s.quantity) AS store_qty,
      sum(s.weight) AS store_weight,
      sum(s.sales) AS store_sales,

      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=1 THEN s.quantity END) AS O_qty,
      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=1 THEN s.weight END) AS O_weight,
      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=1 THEN s.sales END) AS O_sales
    FROM movementweekly s
    JOIN #temp_itemdetail i ON i.upc = s.upc 
    WHERE s.date BETWEEN '2017-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-09 00:00:00'
      --AND ((i.upc >= 5100000000 AND i.upc <= 5100099999) OR (i.upc >= 51000000000 AND i.upc <= 51000999999) OR (i.upc >= 510000000000 AND i.upc <= 510009999999))
    GROUP BY i.upc,i.description,i.size,i.uom,i.price
  ) AS q1
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      s.upc,

      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=2 THEN s.quantity END) AS W_qty,
      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=2 THEN s.weight END) AS W_weight,
      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=2 THEN s.sales END) AS W_sales,

      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=3 THEN s.quantity END) AS S_qty,
      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=3 THEN s.weight END) AS S_weight,
      sum(CASE WHEN s.store=3 THEN s.sales END) AS S_sales
    FROM movementdaily s
    JOIN #temp_itemdetail i ON i.upc = s.upc 
    WHERE s.store IN(2,3)
      AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-09 00:00:00' 
      --AND ((i.upc >= 5100000000 AND i.upc <= 5100099999) OR (i.upc >= 51000000000 AND i.upc <= 51000999999) OR (i.upc >= 510000000000 AND i.upc <= 510009999999))
    GROUP BY s.upc
  ) AS q2 ON q1.upc = q2.upc

ORDER BY q1.store_sales DESC

-- drop temp table
DROP TABLE #temp_itemdetail
```

If the table `movementweekly` contains all the necessary information you can use single query

```
SELECT
  i.upc, i.description, i.size, i.uom, i.price,

  sum(s.quantity) AS store_qty,
  sum(s.weight) AS store_weight,
  sum(s.sales) AS store_sales,

  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=1 THEN s.quantity END) AS O_qty,
  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=1 THEN s.weight END) AS O_weight,
  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=1 THEN s.sales END) AS O_sales,

  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=2 THEN s.quantity END) AS W_qty,
  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=2 THEN s.weight END) AS W_weight,
  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=2 THEN s.sales END) AS W_sales,

  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=3 THEN s.quantity END) AS S_qty,
  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=3 THEN s.weight END) AS S_weight,
  sum(CASE WHEN s.store=3 THEN s.sales END) AS S_sales
FROM movementweekly s
JOIN #temp_itemdetail i ON i.upc = s.upc 
WHERE s.date BETWEEN '2017-01-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-09 00:00:00'
GROUP BY i.upc,i.description,i.size,i.uom,i.price
ORDER BY store_sales DESC
```

Comment: This did drop the load time from one to two minutes, down to ~45 seconds, but that's still too long of a wait. Is there a reason each of the stores' sums can't be done in a single join?

Comment: @Geoff H. - If the table `movementweekly` contains all the necessary information you can use single query. I added it into my answer.